# python pyplot multiple plots in one figure without knowing the exact number

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to plot multiple plots on the same figure and I've seen that I have to use this code (each `x`, `y` is a list):

```
plot(x1,y2,'r',x2,y2,'r',x3,y3,'r'...xn,yn,'r')
```

The problem with this code is that it works only if I know exactly the number of 'n' functions that I'm going to plot.

EG Knowing the number of couples in `eggs`:

```
#eggs = [[[x1],[y1]],[[x2],[y2]],[[x3],[y3]]]
eggs = [[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]],[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,4,8]],[[1,2,3,4],[1,1,1,1]]]

#I know eggs has 3 couple so my plot is...
plot(eggs[0][0],eggs[0][1],'r',eggs[1][0],eggs[1][1],'r',eggs[2][0],eggs[2][1],'r')
```

What if I don't know how many couples are stored into `eggs` and I want to automatize the plots on single figure?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest is to first create your figure, then to loop through your data to add the requested plots.

```
eggs = [[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]],[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,4,8]],[[1,2,3,4],[1,1,1,1]]]

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig,ax = plt.subplots()

for i in range(0,3):
    ax.plot(eggs[i][0],eggs[i][1])
plt.draw()
```

Enjoy :-)